# Particle-Hole Symmetry (Charge-conjugation Symmetry) in CMT

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order, topological-phase

Charge-conjugation symmetry was defined in the bellow paper as follows:

\begin{align}
\hat{\mathcal{C}} \hat{\psi}_A \hat{\mathcal{C}}^{-1} &= \sum_B (U^{*\dagger}_C)_{A,B} \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}_B \\
\hat{\mathcal{C}} \hat{\psi}_A^{\dagger} \hat{\mathcal{C}}^{-1} &= \sum_B \hat{\psi}_B (U_C^{*})_{B,A} \\
\hat{\mathcal{C}} i \hat{\mathcal{C}}^{-1} &= +i
\end{align}
Wich $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is the second quantization charge-conjugation operator.
My question is: Why they defined the unitary matrix $U_{C}$in this way? I understand that when $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ acts on a creation (annihilation) operator, it should annihilate (create). However, why $U_C$ has a "*"?

**Source:** [Topological phases: Classification of topological insulators and superconductors of non-interacting fermions, and beyond](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08882) Equation 15

Comment: You certainly don't have to include the complex conjugation, its just a basis choice the authors have made. See this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500128/particle-hole-symmetry-in-2nd-quantization/709125#709125 for a treatment that does not define the transformation using the complex conjugate of the unitary matrix $U_{C}$